# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1188, 12, 2)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

So when I was trying to build a lstm network, every time it tells me that "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1188, 12, 2)".
My dataset has more than 1000 samples, 2 features, and I set the time_step as 12.
I have already reshaped my dataset to 3-dim, however, the error tells that my last layer-Dense layer(I use this layer as output) expected a 2-dimention array.What shell I do?
My codes are as follows:

```
    # read train set
readColsPro = (7, 20)
filename = 'train_set.txt'
xProTrain_1 = readCsv.csvMat(filename, 1, cols=readColsPro, rows=[0, 1200])
yProTrain_1 = readCsv.csvMat(filename, 1, cols=readColsPro, rows=[1, 1201])

xProTrain_1 = xProTrain_1.reshape(xProTrain_1.shape[0], 2)
yProTrain_1 = yProTrain_1.reshape(yProTrain_1.shape[0], 2)

# erase 'nan' datas
for i in xProTrain_1:
    if np.isnan(i[1]):
        i[1] = 0

for i in yProTrain_1:
    if np.isnan(i[1]):
        i[1] = 0

# read test set
xProTest_1 = readCsv.csvMat(filename, 1, cols=readColsPro, rows=[1, 1201])
yProTest_1 = readCsv.csvMat(filename, 1, cols=readColsPro, rows=[2, 1202])

xProTest_1 = np.reshape(xProTest_1, (xProTest_1.shape[0], xProTest_1.shape[1]))
yProTest_1 = np.reshape(yProTest_1, (yProTest_1.shape[0], yProTest_1.shape[1]))

for i in xProTest_1:
    if np.isnan(i[1]):
        i[1] = 0

for i in yProTest_1:
    if np.isnan(i[1]):
        i[1] = 0

# parameters
timeStepPro = 12
epoch = 24
batch_size = 24
trainNumPro = xProTrain_1.shape[0]
testNumPro = yProTrain_1.shape[0]

# reshape datas to 3D
xProTrain_2 = []
for i in range(timeStepPro, trainNumPro):
    xProTrain_2.append(xProTrain_1[i - timeStepPro:i]) 
xProTrain_2 = np.array(xProTrain_2)

yProTrain_2 = []
for i in range(timeStepPro, trainNumPro):
    yProTrain_2.append(yProTrain_1[i - timeStepPro:i])
yProTrain_2 = np.array(yProTrain_2)
print(xProTrain_2.shape)
print(yProTrain_2.shape)

# reshape datas to 3D
xProTest_2 = []
for i in range(timeStepPro, trainNumPro):
    xProTest_2.append(xProTest_1[i - timeStepPro:i])   
xProTest_2 = np.array(xProTest_2)

yProTest_2 = []
for i in range(timeStepPro, trainNumPro):
    yProTest_2.append(yProTest_1[i - timeStepPro:i])   
yProTest_2 = np.array(yProTest_2)


# define network
modelA = Sequential()
modelA.add(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True,
                input_shape=[xProTrain_2.shape[1], 2]))
modelA.add(BatchNormalization())


modelA.add(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True))

modelA.add(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True))
modelA.add(LSTM(units=256, return_sequences=True))
modelA.add(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=False))


modelA.add(Dense(units=2, activation='relu'))

modelA.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

modelA.fit(x=xProTrain_2, y=yProTrain_2, epochs=epoch, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Error message are as follows:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1188, 12, 2)
```

Comment: A similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51267673/understanding-connecting-a-dense-layer-to-lstm)

Comment: The problem might be in your metric function. You are using `mean_squared_error` as the loss function which is for regression and real, continuous values, but using `accuracy` as a metric function which is for classification and discrete labels. If you're doing regression, you should change the metric function to `mean_squared_error` or `mae`.